# Monotouch.Dialog: IElementSizing not being used

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a Custom element class that only resizes the rows when I rotate the device. On initial display the rows are not resized.

```
public class MultiImageElement : Element, IElementSizing
```

Which implements the `IElementSizing` interface:

```
    #region IElementSizing implementation
    public float GetHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 78;
    }
    #endregion
```

However, this is never called and the row heights remain the default size.

I add elements to my root in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < secFolder.Rows; i++)
{
   sec.Add (new MultiImageElement (secFolder.ThumbnailPathsForRow (i), imageSize));
}
this.Root.Add (sec);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

To have `Monotouch.Dialog` implement the `IElementSizing`, the Sections and Elements must be added to a local "myRoot" variable.

After it's been built out, then set the `Dialog's Root` to that.

```
var myRoot = new Root();
MakeElements()
this.Root = myRoot;
```

This works.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is custom DialogViewController and then setup Root.UevenRows to true:

```
    public class CustomViewController : DialogViewController
    {
        public CustomViewController (RootElement root) : base(root)
        {
            Root.UnevenRows = true;
            ...
        }
        ...
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be related, but happened to me that the initial rotate device event was not fired to me. So I implemented the flag and initiated a scheduled selector to be called upon app start to ensure the ShouldAutorotate... was called and performed the Layout for me if needed.